# Splitting xml nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have this xml:

```
<Forms>
<Form ID="230688" TemplateID="1111" DocType="1">
    <Field name="topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Street[0]" value="street" />
    <Field name="topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].HouseNo[0]" value="18" />
</Form>
<Form ID="230645" TemplateID="5444" DocType="8">
    <Field name="topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].city[0]" value="city_name" />
    <Field name="topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].number[0]" value="345354" />
</Form>
<Form ID="230690" TemplateID="1123" DocType="8">
    <Field name="topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].group[0]" value="group" />
    <Field name="topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].phone[0]" value="phone" />
</Form>
```

I want to produce 4 xml's which every one of them consist of one single form node.

That is produce (one for each Form node):

```
<Forms>
<Form ID="230688" TemplateID="1111" DocType="1">
    <Field name="topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Street[0]" value="street" />
    <Field name="topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].HouseNo[0]" value="18" />
</Form>
</Forms>
```

I tried:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Forms//Form", parser.doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Document outputDoc = _docBuilder.newDocument();
                Element rootElement = outputDoc.createElement("Forms");
                Node childNode = nodeList.item(i);
                rootElement.appendChild(childNode);
                outputDoc.appendChild(rootElement); .....
```

But that gives an exception: "WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it."

Comment: Is your XML correct? Because when I open it in the FireBug, I see that each next node is a child of the previous one. I also see the slash '/' at the end of each <Field> tag, but it does not seem to work. When I explicitly add a </Field> tag after each <Field>, the XML is built into the correct hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [Document.importNode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29)

> Imports a node from another document to this document, without altering or removing the source node from the original document; this method creates a new copy of the source node. The returned node has no parent; (parentNode is null).