# Import node DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to import node from one doc to another:

```
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            DocumentBuilder db2 = dbf2.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc1 =parser.buildDoc(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Document doc2 = db2.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Temp\\workspace2\\Resource2Q\\xml_template.xml")));
            NodeList list = doc1.getElementsByTagName("Form");
            for(int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
                Node copiedNode = doc1.importNode(element, true);
                doc2.getDocumentElement().appendChild(copiedNode); ...
```

The last line of code gives me: "WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it".

Why is this happening? i am importing the node.

Comment: Why not post that as a comment to the answer I gave to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728185/splitting-xml-nodes?

Comment: Sorry, its to long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node copiedNode = doc1.importNode(element, true);
```

should be

```
Node copiedNode = doc2.importNode(element, true);
```

The node comes from doc1, and you want to import it into doc2. Not into doc1, where it already comes from.